# Button with an icon inside it

Tags: html, css, button

I want to know how to add a small icon in this button aligned on left with the text

```
<a class="button" href="#">button</a> 


.button { padding: 15px 15px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg3tK/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a span to your text and put a background aligned to the left for this span.

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span>button</span></a>

.button span {
    background:url('http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-laughing002.gif') no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;}
```

Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/fg3tK/6/

Comment: The extra markup for `span` tag is unnecessary. You can accomplish the same without it, and applying the styles directly to the button itself.

Comment: What if there is a button 200px width and you have variable text length in it? You won't be able to place image next to the text everytime. By hardcoding position of the image, you are doing it wrong. My version will work no matter if the text has 5px width or 150px ;)

Comment: Ohh, I see your perspective. You're saying to have the image directly next to the text vs. having it in a static location within the button. Yes, in that case, you have a wise solution with a fixed button size.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, here is the example - http://jsfiddle.net/u2py3/

[image]

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid #563d7c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
    background-image: 
       url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6);
    background-position-y: 465px;
    background-position-x: 5px;
    background-color: #563d7c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/yDe4z/)**</kbd>

```
.button { 
  background: #000 url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconslandtransport/PNG/24x24/CabrioletRed.png') 5px 45% no-repeat;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 35px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

In case that you have multiple buttons and you want different image for each use `:nth-child()` pseudo class to target each button e.g.

```
.button:nth-child(2) {
  background: red url( ... ) 5px 45% no-repeat;
}
.button:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue url( ... ) 5px 45% no-repeat;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this do it?

```
<a class="button" href="#"><img src="xxx"/>button</a>
```

Or are you looking for somthing more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty common practice to add `padding-left` to your button, and position a `background` to fill that gap that's created.

```
.button {
    background: #666 url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6') 5px -188px no-repeat;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 40px;  /*Add some left padding*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```